# Rotating pool of proxies

Tags: python, proxy

It's a very simple class to get a different proxy each time it's called. I've done it because I was trying to use [aiohttp_scraper](https://github.com/jgontrum/aiohttp-scraper/blob/master/aiohttp_scraper/proxies.py) and it didn't work so I have to make my own. This is just one of the pieces.

```
class Proxies:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = self.download_proxies()
        self.proxy_pool = itertools.cycle(self.proxies)

    def get_proxy(self) -> str:
        return next(self.proxy_pool)
    
    def get_proxies(self) -> List[str]:
        return self.proxies
    
    def download_proxies(self) -> List[str]:
        # This website may be down in the future
        #PROXY_URL = "https://proxy-server.org/"
        #proxies = requests.get(PROXY_URL).text.splitlines()
        proxies = [
            '31.128.248.1:1080',
            '1.85.52.250:9797',
            '103.71.21.238:83',
            '113.176.118.150:1080'
        ]
        random.shuffle(proxies)
        return proxies


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Proxies().get_proxy())
```

Comment: is `proxy-server.org` just a stand-in? Can you share the actual site?

Comment: Looks good except for the missing `import` statements and it wouldn't hurt to include docstrings and comments. A couple of suggestions: (1) Name "private" attributes and methods with a leading '_', e.g. `self._proxies`. Then the only thing other than `__init_` that would be public are methods `get_proxy` and `get_proxies` (unless you see the possibility of a method such as `download_proxies` being overridden). (2) Consider `get_proxies` returning a copy of `self._proxies` so that the client cannot modify your `self._proxies` list.